# WP 8.1 WinRT - Custom tooltip (or UserControl) in maps for a pushpin?

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working with the `MapControl` from the new api for the Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT. What I'm trying to achieve is to display a simple tooltip right above the tapped pushpin (with additional information about the pushpin location). Preferably I'd like that tooltip to be a `UserControl`.

Sadly there's no built-in support from api, neither simple solution for that in web. So far people used to use a ContextMenu feature found in WindowsPhoneToolkit library, unfortunatelly it's Silverlight-only. `Flyout` is also not an option. `ToolTipService` also doesn't work properly.

What I've done so far is to hook up into a pushpin's Tapped event, and then, in code-behind, add a child to the pushpin's `Grid` - but it it doesn't look like a good option, and it makes my pushpin move.

Code XAML:

```
  <maps:MapControl x:Name="Map">
    <maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Pushpins}">
      <maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Grid x:Name="MyGrid"
                Tapped="UIElement_OnTapped">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="*" /> // if grid is tapped I will insert a UserControl to that row
              <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Row="1"
                   Width="24"
                   Height="24"
                   Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PushpinLogoConverter}}"
                   maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location}"
                   maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="1,0.5" />
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </maps:MapItemsControl>
  </maps:MapControl>
```

Code behind:

```
    private void UIElement_OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = (Grid)e.OriginalSource;
        var tooltipBase = new TooltipBase();

        grid.Children.Add(tooltipBase);
        tooltipBase.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
    }
```

Can you tell me if there's a better way to do it? How to make `MyGrid` not to move when I add a children to it? Thanks in advance for any help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Just create a UserControl with a PushPin Icon and a Grid above it with a simple TextBox inside.
Make the Grid invisible by default, and make it Visible once the user click on the pushpin to show all the data that you want.

```
<Grid>
    <Ellipse Fill="#FFF4F4F5" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             Height="50" 
             Stroke="Black" 
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Width="50" 
             Tapped="Ellipse_Tapped"/>
    <Grid x:Name="locationInfoGrid"
          Margin="0,-100,0,0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="100" 
          Height="100" 
          Background="#FFB4B4B4">

        <TextBlock x:Name="locationInfo"
                   FontSize="14"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
    private void Ellipse_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        locationInfo.Text = "Location info here";

        if (locationInfoGrid.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            locationInfoGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        else
            locationInfoGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Then simply add the UsercControl to your Map at the specific location.

```
        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyUserControl1 uc = new MyUserControl1();
        MyMap.Children.Insert(0, uc);
        MapControl.SetLocation(uc, location);
        MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(uc, new Point(0.5, 1));
    }
```